# Built in table with users email and password only allows every other user to log in

Tags: mysql, vb.net, authentication

I have a vb.net app with a mysql database and a table for users emails and passwords. I started noticing that some could log in and others could not, so I tried all user accounts myself and found that all of the odd number indexed logins work and all of the even number indexed logins do not. I don't have a clue as to why this is not working.

Code below:

```
Partial Public Class Login

    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Email.Focus()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click


        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

        Dim rdr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader

        Dim query As String
        Dim name As String = ""
        Dim time_out As Integer
        Dim user_access As Integer
        Dim pswrd As String
        Dim e_mail As String
        Dim firstname As String
        Dim lastname As String



        Try

            conn = New MySqlConnection(connStr)

            conn.Open()

            query = "SELECT * FROM user"

            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            Do While rdr.HasRows = True

                firstname = ""
                lastname = ""
                pswrd = ""
                time_out = 0
                user_access = 1

                rdr.Read()

                firstname = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("first_name"))
                lastname = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("last_name"))
                e_mail = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("email"))
                pswrd = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("password"))
                user_access = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("access"))
                time_out = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("timeout"))


                If pswrd = Password.Text And e_mail = Email.Text Then

                    session_email = e_mail
                    session_access = user_access
                    session_timeout = time_out
                    session_first = firstname

                    Session("Session_User") = session_email
                    Session("Session_TimeOut") = time_out
                    Session("Session_Access") = session_access
                    Session("Session_First") = session_first

                    Response.Write(session_first & " your access level is ... " & session_access & vbCrLf & "With an access level of... " _
                        & vbCrLf & "1 You can create work orders And view most other things" _
                        & vbCrLf & "2 You can create work orders,  View and or Modify some items. Please be careful" _
                        & vbCrLf & "3 You have full Create, Edit and Delete access. Please be careful Jedi Master!" _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You have " & time_out & " minutes to complete your task.", vbSystemModal, "Logged In")

                    GoTo JumpPoint2

                End If


                If rdr.Read() = False Then

                    Response.Write("Your Login Attempt Failed " & vbCrLf & "Either your email address or password are NOT correct" & vbCrLf & "or you do not have access to this system yet." & vbCrLf & "Contact Management if you need an account set up for you.", vbSystemModal, "Log In Failure")

                    GoTo JumpPoint1

                End If

            Loop
JumpPoint1:
        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write("Login Fail by Exception : " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)

        End Try

JumpPoint2:

        conn.Close()

        If session_access = "1" Or session_access = "2" Or session_access = "3" Then

            Response.Redirect("~/MainMenu.aspx")

        End If

    End Sub

End Class


End of Code:
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Never ever store passwords as plain text

Comment: Will get there eventually. New at vb.net and MySQL. Overwhelmed with all the examples.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are calling .Read twice for each iteration in your loop, which will skip every other row.  Change your loop to this:

```
Dim bolValidated As Boolean = False

Do While rdr.Read()

     ..
     'Update bolValidated to True if you find a match.'


Loop

If Not bolValidated Then

    Response.Write("Your Login Attempt Failed ...")

End If
```

The better solution though would to change your SQL statement to reduce processing:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM User WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password
```

Wrapping the connection in a using statement wouldn't be a bad idea either.